# how can apps such as onavo intercept internet traffic from other apps

Tags: ios

How is it possible to intercept the traffic the mobile phone has with any server? How can you create a proxy that intercepts traffic from any app the user installed on their device? Don't applications run in a sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it works by proxying the data and putting compression in front of the mobile device.

> Onavo Extend installs a configuration profile (which includes your
>   operator’s APN settings) on your device so that data you receive from
>   the Internet is compressed in our cloud-based compression service,
>   located in datacenters operated by Amazon Web Services. The compressed
>   data is then sent to your mobile device so that you get a leaner,
>   faster and more efficient version of the web.

This could be achieved either by [VPN with compression](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-ipcu/?lang=en-us#appbec2bfec), or by [changing the APN](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-ipcu/?lang=en-us#appbec2b702).

The above quote is taken from the Help/FAQ [here](http://www.onavo.com/apps/iphone_extend_help).

Comment: Is there are way for an app in the background to be told when network activity is happening on the phone? I'm trying to create a parental control app and want to log all the URL's requested

Answer (score 1):

[from macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1493450)

Nov 20, 2012, 08:49 PM    #1
petrucci666
macrumors 6502

Join Date: Apr 2009
Onavo suddenly creates VPN network
I've been using Onavo pretty much since it came out, and it's a terrific app that solves a true problem. I know tey constantly update the profile they install on your iPhone, but suddenly Onavo is connecting via VPN.

I have never seen this before. Why is it using VPN, and not just doing it the way it used to?
    0
 Nov 21, 2012, 03:58 AM    #2
onavo
macrumors newbie

Join Date: Feb 2012

Hi Petrucci666,
Firstly, thank you for the positive feedback regarding our apps. We're really glad to hear that youve had positive Onavo experiences so far.

**We've been upgrading our app's infrastructure to VPN in order to address some carrier-specific bugs that have affecting some of our users. Using VPN instead of APN allows us to continue helping our users while eliminating certain carrier-specific problems some users have been experiencing.**

Sorry for the surprise VPN update and thanks a lot for reaching out to us!